# Bash 'scp' command with parameters

Tags: bash, parameters, cygwin, scp

I'm totally new in Bash programming, so please don't feel offended with my question.
I'm trying to use SCP command with parameters from configuration file. Now my code looks like below

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

source $1

echo $HOST
echo $USER
echo $DIRECTORY

scp ${USER}@${HOST}:/${DIRECTORY}/file.zip .
```

And my output is:

```
111.111.11.111
user1
/home/repo/test/
: Name or service not knowname 111.111.11.111
```

If I will remove ${HOST} from command and I'll paste address directly, it's working perfectly. 
Other variables are passed without problem. 
Do you have any idea where I'm doing it wrong? I am completely lost.
I'm running this script from Cygwin terminal, but I think it's not a problem.

Comment: Have you tried with following syntax? `scp ${USER}@$HOST:/${DIRECTORY}/file.zip .`

Comment: Yes, and it's the same

Comment: Just tried by removing all the '{' and '}' and it works fine in my system, that is: `scp $USER@$HOST:/$DIRECTORY/file.zip .`

Comment: Can it be that some of the strings contain some nonprintable characters (`\r` or so?).

Comment: You are right! I changed EOL conversion for config file to UNIX and it's working! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Jakuje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196426/jakuje) comment, the problem was in config file. I've changed EOL conversion to UNIX and it's working perfectly.